# Serializing circe.Json in Flink

Tags: scala, apache-flink, circe

**Scala Flink** has problems serializing json in **circe.Json** format.

I am using lib [flink-adt](https://github.com/findify/flink-adt) to derive **TypeInformation** that contains the serializer.

```scala
  implicit val jsonInfo: TypeInformation[Json] =
    deriveTypeInformation[Json]
```

Here is the error message:

```
magnolia: child class BiggerDecimalJsonNumber of class JsonNumber is neither final nor a case class
```

I also tried this.

```scala
  implicit val jsonInfo: TypeInformation[Json] =
    TypeInformation.of(classOf[Json])
```

It compiles but crashes when I run unit test.

Comment: can you provide a stack trace of `TypeInformation.of(classOf[Json])` crash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the serializer to work by adding `new ExecutionConfig()`

This code worked:

```scala
import io.circe._
import io.circe.syntax._
import org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation
import org.apache.flink.api.common.ExecutionConfig

    implicit val jsonTypeInformation: TypeInformation[Json] =
      TypeInformation.of(classOf[Json])
    val typeInformation = implicitly[TypeInformation[Json]]
    val json = """[{"level":"up","num":1.23,"valid":true}]""".asJson
    val ser = typeInformation.createSerializer(new ExecutionConfig())
    roundtrip(ser, json)
```